# Initial Data Load with Rails API + Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm currently using Ruby on Rails and EmberJS for a project. The Rails app is an ecommerce store and will need ~10 models to be loaded initially. I was thinking of using [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to pass the models down as json on initial page load.

I'm thinking of using the ember cli to make one project, and, of course, ruby on rails to make the API.

If I make the application separate, how does one do initial data load? When it comes to deployment, how do you make sure that everything runs off of one rails server (thinking Heroku)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only using Rails (without Ember CLI), you could render the gon object in the application layout per [gon's instructions](https://github.com/gazay/gon) and just pluck your data off of the gon global. Good place to do this might be your application route in Ember:

```
// routes/application.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return gon.myDataSet;
  }
});
```

However, I would recommend using Ember CLI, which if you do, cuts your rails application layout (and thus gon) out of the equation. Instead, simply open up json endpoints on your rails application where you can then fetch it in your Ember application:

```
// routes/application.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/path/in/rails/app');
  }
});
```

Then while you're in development run your rails server in one terminal, and then run your ember server (from the CLI directory) with the proxy option:

```
$ ember server --proxy http://localhost:3000
```

As for deploying, that's a whole can of worms, but check out [ember-cli-deploy](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-deploy) as it aims to be the one stop shop for deploying ember apps.

Comment: The solution here was actually to have Rails serve up the ember application as a static asset and use Deface to perform what a coworker termed "technological rape" by manually inserting the rendered JSON into say public/index.html. I'm guessing this is why they called Deface, deface... https://github.com/spree/deface

Comment: While you can certainly accomplish this in this way, it doesn't feel idiomatic to Ember. One of the great benefits of Ember CLI in particular is that you can develop your front end completely isolated from your backend api. However, that's not necessarily what you are asking here, but I think it's still good to throw out there.